# Prevent <script> execution after use html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a widget that replace some text contents to my clients in a particular section.
So to achieve it I need to use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method that replace all with the new content, but after this, If my client has `<script> ... </script>` these are executed again!

is there any way to prevent the execution of these scripts?

I would apreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without seeing the code. But it sounds like you're reusing elements that have already been used. If so, just remove the script tags before passing that into `html` again.

Comment: I know it's difficult without code, If I delete those scripts, do you think the client will have any problems?

Comment: Not if they've already been run once. Deleting a `script` element has no effect on the code it introduced into the environment (unlike deleting a stylesheet).

Comment: You're right! I'll try deleting script, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @T.J. Crowder said... removing the scripts was the better solution. thanks man =)

Answer (score 0):

You can load your client's code into an `<iframe>` and use the [sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute to prevent the client's js execution. The `<iframe>` element provides security against XSS.